# Python Pandas Dataframe challenge: how do I avoid Iterrows() for this scenario?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

**Context**

I've heard it often said "you should avoid iterating through a Dataframe", or "using iterrows is bad/slow/etc." or "there is nothing you can do with iterrows that you can't do with apply/applymap/map". I'm trying to shed the habit of using iterrows but have found a scenario I have not as yet been able to work a way around using apply/applymap/map. I'm hoping some df guru can help me out.

**Overview of logic/scenario**
I have a {set} of unique values that correspond to a column in my dataframe. The dataframe is transactional - I need to compare element[0] in my set to  of my dataset, where the values match: append the value of  to a list. On a complete run of the dataset (appending a list of all possible values) - pass that list as a value in dictionary (with element[0] being the key). Repeat for all {set} elements.

**Main Challenges**

1. I am not applying a function per element - I am comparing a {set} element to a dataframe column where it matches an arbitary number of times: append the element in a different column to a list (not df)
2. After one complete pass of the df, take that compiled list and pass to a dictionary (again, not a df)

All examples I've seen: apply/applymap/map work on every element in a series or dataframe - not (for example) just 2 columns out of a potential 5. Or comparing values on column 1 and 4 then appending column 10 to a structure outside of the dataframe.

**Current Solution (looking to improve on)**
'''
# Convert to set - make unique
job_set = set(job_list)

```
results_dict = dict()
# loop through set, append all runs associated per job number:
for job in job_set:
    temp_list = list()
    for idx, val in dict_val.iterrows():
        if val['JobNumber'] == job:
            temp_list.append(val['RunNumber'])

    # append to new dict - {job number : [list of runs]}
    results_dict[job] = temp_list
```

'''

**Sample Data**
'''
JobNumber,RunNumber,Brief Created Date
10000,9,8/03/17
1667,2166,5/05/18
1667,2165,5/05/18
1667,2153,8/04/18
1710,3602,24/06/18
1710,3600,22/06/18
1710,3594,18/06/19
1710,3589,11/06/19
1710,3492,5/03/18
1710,3456,27/01/18
2265,1436,3/06/18
2265,1429,6/05/19
2265,1418,8/04/19
3708,459,9/04/19
3708,109,4/06/19
3708,402,26/03/19
3938,401,19/03/19
3938,400,12/03/19
3938,399,5/03/19
3938,391,6/01/19
3938,0,5/03/19
4529,2117,24/06/19
4529,1736,29/03/19
4529,143,30/03/19
4529,1158,9/03/19
4669,374,17/05/19
4813,30,5/01/19
5651,62,1/06/18
5651,61,6/04/19
5651,60,16/03/19
'''

**Sample Data Added**

Please let me know if you need more details. My challenge is simply to attempt to complete this using the 'preferred' methods of apply or applymap or map. My main intention is implimenting best practices around optimised execution times.

Like I mentioned: all use cases for these methods seem to center on the dataframe/series element-level - I need a way to compare values acorss a whole dataset, then bring the result into a new data structure, rinse and repeat.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you provide an example dataframe? with the necessary columns, and some rows? It would make it easier to understand.

Comment: There's nearly always a way to apply a function across rows, you just need to know the appropriate pandas functions to apply. As @SawradipSaha says, if you provide a minimal reproducible example, I am happy to give it a go

Comment: Hi all - thanks for your comments, sample dataset added now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
results_dict = dict()
for job in job_set:
    filt = (dict_val['JobNumber'] == job)  #this creates a filter/mask with only the jobs you want
    new_df = dict_val[filt] #this applies gives a subdataframe only with desired columns
    temp_list = new_df['RunNumber'].tolist()
    results_dict[job] = temp_list
```

I couldn't run the code as you didn't provide any example dataframe, so in can have some typo. But I hope you get the logic.

Comment: Sawradip you legend that sped the query up 87% (23.5s -> 3s)  thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Looks like what you want is a groupby into list?

```
In [1]:
   ...: import pandas as pd
   ...:
   ...:
   ...: df = pd.DataFrame(
   ...:     {
   ...:         "JobNumber": [1,1,3,4,5,5],
   ...:         "RunNumber": [1,2,3,4,5,6],
   ...:     }
   ...: )
   ...:
   ...: df.groupby('JobNumber')['RunNumber'].apply(list)
   ...:
Out[1]:
JobNumber
1    [1, 2]
3       [3]
4       [4]
5    [5, 6]
Name: RunNumber, dtype: object
```

Comment: Ryan - great solution. How do I maintain a unique list of 'JobNumbers' per list of 'RunNumbers'?

Comment: Instead of `apply(list)`, doing `apply(set)` with remove the duplicates.

Comment: Hi Ryan - I mean how do I output 2 columns. <col1> list of job numbers (unique), <col2> list of runs?

Comment: I see, I would do `df.groupby('JobNumber')['RunNumber'].apply(list).reset_index()` for that.

Answer (score 0):

This dictionary comprehension can be applied in one line:

```
results_dict = {job_num: list(df.apply(lambda x: set(x).intersection(job), axis=1)) for job_num, job in enumerate(job_set)}
```

Comment: Hi Tom - this didn't work for me. Thanks alot for the suggestion. I did append a csv dataset to give an idea of what I'm working with. Maybe if you get a sec that will help you.